# How to make JPA enforce the right FK constraint among many of them?

Tags: java-8, eclipselink, db2-luw, jpa-2.1

I have 4 tables : TABLE_A, TABLE_B, TABLE_C, TABLE_RESULT

Constraints :

1. FK_TABLE_A_ID is a foreign key refrerences IDA primary key in TABLE_A
2. FK_TABLE_B_ID is a foreign key refrerences IDB primary key in TABLE_B
3. FK_TABLE_C_ID is a foreign key refrerences IDC primary key in TABLE_C
4. Only one foreign column is set at the same time

Table_A :

| IDA | Field_A1 | Field_AN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dataA11 | dataA12 |
| 2 | dataA21 | dataA22 |
| 3 | dataA32 | dataA32 |

Table_B :

| IDB | Field_B1 | Field_BN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dataB11 | dataB12 |
| 2 | dataB21 | dataB22 |
| 3 | dataB32 | dataB32 |

Table_C :

| IDC | Field_C1 | Field_CN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dataB11 | dataB12 |
| 2 | dataB21 | dataB22 |
| 3 | dataB32 | dataB32 |

TABLE_RESULT:

| ID | FK_TABLE_A_ID | FK_TABLE_B_ID | FK_TABLE_C_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | 2 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | 3 |

Not allowed cases :

| ID | FK_TABLE_A_ID | FK_TABLE_B_ID | FK_TABLE_C_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | 3 |
| 4 | NULL | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Some tables are in production environnement, and this design is imposed i don't have other options like refactoring the existing code or modifying the db schema.

1. I'm wondering how to map those relations in order to enforce the 4th constraint. Any suggestions and hints will be appreciated
2. Is it possible to make FK_TABLE_A_OR_B_OR_C_ID reference multiple columns on multiple tables and add a new TYPE column to know which table is referenced.

| ID | FK_TABLE_A_OR_B_OR_C_ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2 | B |
| 3 | 3 | C |

Comment: If the goal is to enforce not more than one NOT NULL value in 3 columns for each row, then you may use, say, before insert and update triggers with the corresponding check. If not, then describe your goal in more detail, since the "map those relations" request is vague.

Comment: This is either entirely application side logic, where you check the entity and ensure only 1 reference is set in code (or an entity level validator) or you do it entirely in the database with insert/update trigger checks. But there is no JPA mapping mechanism that handles this.

Comment: A check constraint on the table with the same expression is probably a better solution.